# Why do K (and others) oppose Wallace?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

In Blade Runner 2049, Wallace wants to capture the replicant child so that he can dissect it, study it, and create replicants capable of breeding.

Meanwhile, the replicant rebels want to use the child as proof of replicant reproduction, arguing that replicants should have the same rights as normal humans.

This seems counterproductive.  Wouldn't it serve the replicant rebellion's interests if Wallace were able to create *more* replicants capable of breeding?

Answer (score 5):

WARNING: SPOILERS

For K and other replicants, the replicant who was born is a hero to them. It represents the first proof that they are not just "things", but that they are living beings who can reproduce and should be given rights. The reason they don't want Wallace to study the replicant child is because Wallace plans to treat it like a "thing":  study it, dissect it, and ultimately kill it.  He will then *manufacture* more replicants like it, again treating their kind as a thing.

There may also be metaphors related to early Christianity going on. There are believers in the one who is a miracle (as at least one of the replicants described the replicant who was born). Wallace wants to kill their "savior", so of course they are trying to protect her.